# WAF/IDS detection question

Tags: ids, detection, waf

I've been writing scripts to identify WAF's on websites, and have come across one that appears, A LOT.

The HTML always looks like this:

```
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You don't have permission to access /<SOME-LINK> on this server.</p>
<hr>
```

My question is, does anybody know what protection this is? I've read somewhere that it is `ModSecurity`, but I haven't been able to prove this (mostly because it doesn't say that). Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you (also if there is a giant list of known WAF's and their HTML that I don't know about would someone be able to point me in the right direction).

Comment: have you googled "You don't have permission to access / on this server" ? There are a lot of responses ... and none of them WAF or IDSs ...

Comment: @schroeder yes I have, that's why I was confused because of how many responses there are

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of the above. It's a default Apache message for page security.

Source: 
https://github.com/apache/httpd/blob/29ddc70d4aa6847c46d8b8659ff0fbfd39308382/modules/http/http_protocol.c#L991

Comment: Awh that makes sense as to why so many of them produce it, thank you that helps a lot!

Answer (score 0):

That is not a WAF. As others said, it seems a default Apache message.

Anyway, to try to identify a WAF you can check a script called [WafW00f](https://github.com/EnableSecurity/wafw00f). That's included on some pentesting linux distributions like Kali Linux or Parrot Security, or you can download it from Github on the link I already put above.

Comment: Thank you, already have that, implementing one into a program I'm creating